# Box Cutter showing up edge lines

Tags: add-on, edit-mode, faces, edges, lines

I am in very beginner level for 3d Modelling and I have a question.

When I use box cutter, in edit mode some extra edge lines show up on the surface like this. Is this normal? Thank you for answers.
[image]

Comment: You can't create a hole in a face without 2 edges connecting the inner edges to the outer edges, therefore these edges

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a hole within a face without 2 edges connecting the inner edges to the outer edges, therefore these edges:

[image]